# DynamoDB update fails when nested path not exists

Tags: javascript, amazon-dynamodb, dynamodb-queries, documentclient

My table structure is below where `time` is the unique key and that "01" was the id of the count, the item of a month will create right after any id get the count result of that month.

```
{
  "details": {
    "01": {
      "a": {
        "count": [10, 5]
      },
      "b": {
        "count": [10, 5]
      }
    }
  },
  "time": "2020_06"
}
```

And I use update function to save the count result:

```
var params = {
  TableName: tableName,
  Key: { time },
  UpdateExpression: `ADD details.#id.#type.count[0] :count0, details.#id.#type.count[1] :count1`,
  ExpressionAttributeNames: {
    '#id': id,
    '#type': type
  },
  ExpressionAttributeValues: {
    ':count0': count[0],
    ':count1': count[1]
  },
  ReturnValues: 'ALL_NEW'
}
```

If the result of the id already exists then that's fine. But if it doesn't, I'll get an error says that

```
ValidationException: The document path provided in the update expression is invalid for update
```

How to let the map be constructed before updating data? I had tried to use `SET if_not_exists()` but it'll overlap the path what I really want to update (the count array)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short you cannot, there are 2 options I can think on.

1. When creating the item create an empty map for `details`. This will allow you to update nested values for `details` without raising an exception about an invalid path.
2. Add some exception handling which will update the entire map should it throw and exception on the first execution:

```
import boto3
from botocore.exceptions import ClientError

table = boto3.resource('dynamodb', region_name='eu-west-1').Table('test1')

try:
    table.update_item(
        Key={
            'pk': '1'
        },
        UpdateExpression="SET #buyer.#value = :val1, #buyer.#label = :val2",
        ExpressionAttributeNames={
            '#label': 'label',
            '#value': 'value',
            '#buyer': 'buyer',
        },
        ExpressionAttributeValues={
            ':val1': 'id1',
            ':val2': 'Test'
        }
    )
except ClientError as e:
       if e.response['Error']['Code'] == 'ValidationException':
            # Creating new top level attribute `buyer` (with nested props)
            # if the previous query failed
            response = table.update_item(
                Key={
                    'pk': '1'
                },
                UpdateExpression="set #buyer = :val1",
                ExpressionAttributeNames={
                    '#buyer': 'buyer'
                },
                ExpressionAttributeValues={
                    ':val1': {
                        'value': 'id1',
                        'label': 'Test'
                    }
                }
            )
        else:
            raise
```