# Pass variable name as column name in Dynamodb UpdateExpression python

Tags: python, amazon-dynamodb

How can I pass a variable name in Dynamocdb UpdateExpression, using python.

file is the variable that i want to put in UpdateExpression. When I use like below it gives me

```
"[ERROR] ClientError: An error occurred (ValidationException) when calling the UpdateItem operation: The document path provided in the update expression is invalid for update

response = table.update_item(
        Key={"runid": item["runid"]},
        UpdateExpression="SET " + file + "= :val1, update_date = :val2",
        ExpressionAttributeValues={
            ":val1": item[file],
            ":val2": item["update_date"],
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

The exception states you're trying to update a nested attribute in a map which does not exist.

For example,

`SET mymap['nested_attribute'] = xyz`

In this case the attribute `mymap` does not exist in the item and throww the exception you're seeing.

Refer to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62581784/dynamodb-update-fails-when-nested-path-not-exists) for more.